# Temporarily hide TODO from showing in the Show Document Items list in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

Sometimes when I am working on a project, I want to be able to use the jump bar to quickly access methods in the current file, however, the TODOs also appear there making it difficult to find what I want.

Is there a way to temporarily not show the TODOs there?

I'm using Xcode 4.6.

Comment: Don't use so many TODO's. Maybe even "Do" some of them.

Comment: @Abizern: For certain things, it's more productive to document them directly in Xcode, rather than entering them in somewhere else. Plus, I get a reference to exactly where it needs to be done.

Comment: I don't entirely disagree. I use TODOs as well for some things, but for stuff I really want to get done and reminded of I use #warnings: http://abizern.org/cocoa-coding-conventions/#TODOs